# Create apache vhost with php

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I am trying to find a way for php to create a vhost config for apache so a user can enter there domain in and I can direct it to a given folder. Is this even possible to do with php? Or would I be better off using .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I looked all over and I can't find a clear answer to this problem. Basicly, I need php to write something to apache that points a domain to a given folder.

Comment: you can tell apache to look in a folder for vhost config files, and you can create a file on the fly. You would have to tell php to reload the apache config by running a system command so it recognizes the new vhost config, then have php create the associated folder, etc..., not that that's the most secure thing in the world.

Comment: It is almost certainly going to be preferable to have a single, static configuration which uses `mod_rewrite` or similar. Apache does not scale well with a very large number of virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I think I found a system that will work great